# get a "from" date and "to" date from a string

Tags: javascript

`var string = '1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS'`

I would like to get a date from the above string, remove all the other content and return like the below:

`['2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '201801', '201812']`

Basically, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-MM-DD, YYYMM, YYYYMM.

I have tried the following but couldn't progress more:

`var res = string.match(/\d{2}([\/.-])\d{2}\1\d{4}/g);`

`=> ['01/01/2018', '31/12/2018']`

Then another function is to get the YYYYMM part.

`var arr = res[0].split("-");`
`return arr[0]+arr[1];`
`=> '201801'`

Is it possible to get the four elements in a single array in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But if you want, you can extract everything in one step.

```js
function extractDates (string) {
    let result = /(?<!\d)(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})-(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})(?!\d)/.exec(string);
    return result? [
        `${result[3]}-${result[2]}-${result[1]}`,
        `${result[6]}-${result[5]}-${result[4]}`,
        `${result[3]}${result[2]}`,
        `${result[6]}${result[5]}`
    ]: null;
}

let string = '1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS';
console.log(extractDates(string));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it in two steps. Find the dates, then format them.

```js
var string = '1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS';

const formatDateParts = (string) => {
    const [day, month, year] = string.split('/');
    return [[year, month, day].join('-'), `${year}${month}`];
};

const [_, date1, date2] = string.match(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/);

const [date1Format, date1Condensed] = formatDateParts(date1);
const [date2Format, date2Condensed] = formatDateParts(date2);

const result = [date1Format, date2Format, date1Condensed, date2Condensed];

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Forget to mention to remove the other contents. Just interested in the dates

Comment: I think OP wants yearMonth, not yearDay. **201812** the 12 is the month

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but this answer may be more readable / clean

```js
var string = "1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS";
// Get each date
var dates = string.match(/(\d+\/){2}\d+/g);
// Split each date into day, month & year
dates = dates.map(i => i.split("/"));
// Format into desired format
// ['2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '201801', '201812']
dates = [
    `${dates[0][2]}-${dates[0][1]}-${dates[0][0]}`,
    `${dates[1][2]}-${dates[1][1]}-${dates[1][0]}`,
    `${dates[0][2]}${dates[0][1]}`,
    `${dates[1][2]}${dates[1][1]}`,
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = "1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS"

let regex = /(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(19|20)\d{2})-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(19|20)\d{2})/

res = data.match(regex)
let x = res[1].split("/")
let y = res[3].split("/")
[res[1].replaceAll("/", "-"), res[3].replaceAll("/", "-"), x[2] + x[1], y[2] + y[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const string = '1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS';

// Extract the date range using regex
const dateRangeRegex = /(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})-(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/;
const dateRangeMatch = string.match(dateRangeRegex);
const startDate = dateRangeMatch[1];
const endDate = dateRangeMatch[2];

// Convert the start and end dates to the desired format
const startDateFormatted = startDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');
const endDateFormatted = endDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');

// Extract the year and month from the start and end dates
const yearMonthStart = startDate.substring(6, 10) + startDate.substring(3, 5);
const yearMonthEnd = endDate.substring(6, 10) + endDate.substring(3, 5);

// Create the resulting array
const result = [startDateFormatted, endDateFormatted, yearMonthStart, yearMonthEnd];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable version of blakkwater's version

```js
const dateRangeRE = /(?<!\d)(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})-(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})(?!\d)/;
const extractDates = (string) => {
  const [match, dd1, mm1, yyyy1, dd2, mm2, yyyy2] = dateRangeRE.exec(string) || [];
  // if a match return the array else return null
  return match && [              
    `${yyyy1}-${mm1}-${dd1}`, `${yyyy2}-${mm2}-${dd2}`,
    `${yyyy1}${mm1}`,         `${yyyy2}${mm2}`
  ] || null;                     
};

let string1 = '1: Mode: SOME Date range: 01/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS';
console.log(extractDates(string1));
let string2 = '2: Mode: not matching regex: 1/01/2018-31/12/2018 User: HANS';
console.log(extractDates(string2));
```